# 'setuptool' utility for CentOS 5.5 is not showing all the options I'd expect

Tags: centos, httpd, centos5, apache-2.2

I'm trying to setup a server for the first time. I'm running CentOS 5.5. In the book that I'm going through called "The definitive Guide to CentOS", it says in the chapter about setting up the Apache Httpd webserver that in order to configure the firewall, I should run the 'setuptool' utility which gives a nice-ish GUI for configuring various things.

Only thing is that my setuptool is only showing one option - Authentication Configuration, whereas the one in the book has lots of options, including the one that I want which is Firewall configuration. this is what I see onmy computer:

[image: This is what I see on my computer]

and this is what the book says that I should see:

[image: This is what the book says that I should see]

Can anyone tell me what I'd need to do to get setuptool to have all the options I need?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install the various `system-config-*` packages.